# Send item to Sketchup with brushed metal material

Tags: texturing

I'm new at this stuff, so I'm trying to send stuff to sketchup with a brushed metal detail. But the brushed material doesn't show on the preview. What is it I'm doing wrong? Do I have to bake it? How do I bake brushed metal, which I'm trying to do?

[image: this is brushed metal]